# Materialize Button only works when clicked some parts

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Hello I have created a button with Materialize, but it only works for some areas of the button (primarily the area that surrounds the text). Any reason for this?

In my form all I do is add another input like this:

```
<input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Log In!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" />
```

But when I click on the button only the boxed area actually recognizes it as input:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example with this behavior, and as much supporting information as necessary (browser, version, etc.)

Comment: I just have a simple form with that Log In button to call a script that verifies the user against the database. However no actions are carried out unless I click specifically on the Log In! text. I am using Chrome and when inspecting elements I noticed that the outer part is highlighted with

    <i class="waves-effect waves-light btn waves-input-wrapper">

while the actual input area is highlighted with just the input code.

Comment: Please update question with more HTML.  Your comment mentions `<i>` element, but you don't show that anywhere...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Materialize wraps the input tag in an "i" tag, which is then rendered into a button-looking element, with clickability limited to the text portion.

I was able to solve this by simply transforming my input tag into a button tag.

Initial code:

```
<input type="submit" value="List Employees" id="fetch-employees" 
class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
```

What is then rendered in the browser:

```
<i class="waves-effect waves-light btn waves-input-wrapper" style="">
    <input type="submit" value="List Employees" id="fetch-employees" 
    class="waves-button-input">
</i>
```

Solution:

```
<button type="submit" value="List Employees" id="fetch-employees" 
class="waves-effect waves-light btn">List Employees</button>
```